# Navigation bar color not changing on cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to Cordova and currently, I'm using this plugin [Cordova Plugin](https://github.com/fagundes/cordova-plugin-navigationbar) to change the color of my navigation bar. As per the documentation, I have added the preferences in my config.xml file.

```
<preference name="NavigationBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
<preference name="NavigationBarLight" value="true" />
```

and I have also tried changing using

```
NavigationBar.backgroundColorByName(String colorName, Boolean lightNavigationBar = false);
```

it doesn't work. The Splash screen has a black navigation bar however on the next page it turns to white. [image: Nav bar white at bottom]

[image: Desired output]

Tried including it in `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);` still not working

Any inputs will be helpful, Not sure where I'm going wrong.Thanks in advance

Navigation bar hide is working but unable to change the color

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem. I started studying the code of StatusBar and NavigationBar and found out that they are very similar. I do not know how Java works, but I saw a discrepancy and replaced it.

C:\projects\app-kit-cordovaReact\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\viniciusfagundes\cordova\plugin\navigationbar\NavigationBar.java

```
 //window.getClass().getDeclaredMethod - does not work

 window.getClass().getMethod("setNavigationBarColor", int.class).invoke(window, 
 Color.parseColor(colorPref)); - works
```